# How do I delete node_modules folder quickly?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, node-modules

When I want to delete a node_modules folder it takes ages when I delete it using Windows Explorer. How do I delete faster?

Comment: You are using windows?

Answer (score 5):

I use to have the same issue, taking hours to achieve the deletion until I found this workaround:

1. **Select** the node_modules folder. Do this with the file explorer.
2. Open Powershell **as admin**: press **Alt+F**, then **S**, then **A**.
3. Wait and **accept** to open Powershell **as admin**
4. **Paste** this command and press **Enter**: `del /f/q/s *.* > nul`.

**WARNING**

**Please be sure to be in the folder `node_modules`. I mean, that the terminal path ends with `...\node_modules`.**

> In the above command, we use the `/f` switch to force the deletion of read-only files. The `/q` switch enables quiet mode. The `/s` switch executes the command for all files in any folder inside the folder you’re trying to remove. Using `*.*` tells the del command to delete every file and `> nul` disables the console output improving performance and speed.

6. Wait for the process to take action.
7. Now go up one level in the directory with `cd..`.
8. Finally use this command to delete the **node_modules** folder `rmdir /q/s node_modules`

> In the above command, we use the /q switch to enable quiet mode, the /s switch to run the command on all the folders, and `node_modules` is the variable you need to specify to delete the folder you want.

---

If you get an error with **Powershell** try other terminals as administrator like **Windows Terminal**, **Command Prompt (cmd)** or third party terminals like **ConEmu**. I made this steps with **Cmder** and all the deletion was done in just 5 minutes. Off course this duration is variable according to the size of the folder.

---

References:

[pureinfotech.com](https://pureinfotech.com/delete-large-folder-fast-windows-10/)

[ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)

[Cmder](https://cmder.net/)

Answer (score 2):

From you project folder use following command to delete it:
`rd .\node_modules\ /s /q`

Comment: I don't have a command `rd` on Linux Fedora. Is it quicker to obtain it, or use the command `npm uninstall`?

Answer (score 0):

Running the command `Remove-Item -Path "directory_or_file_path" -Recurse -Force` instantly delete node_modules for me on VSCode. [How to Delete Node Modules in VSCode?](https://tooabstractive.com/how-to-tech/remove-item-a-parameter-cannot-be-found-that-matches-parameter-name-rf/)